# Write a lint check for android,where should I place the jar?

Tags: android, lint

I just follow the link: [Write a lint check](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-custom-rules) and writed a lint check .jar.

and follow the website, I should place it there:

```
$ mkdir ~/.android/lint/
$ cp customrule.jar ~/.android/lint/
```

But my computer's os is win7 and can not create a folder like this name: `.android`

so where should I place it?

I try place it in the `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` and it's subfolder,it doesn't work at all.

Comment: c:users/yourusername/.android/lint may be this

Comment: Have you tried using `$ANDROID_LINT_JARS`? Check: [Lint custom rules](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-custom-rules).